# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-generic-views

here's my files:

1. views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    from . import forms
    from django.views.generic import CreateView
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView


    class SignUp(CreateView):
        form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
        template_name = "webportal/signup.html"


    class HelloPage(TemplateView):
        template_name = "hello.html"
```

2.apps urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = "webportal"


urlpatterns = [
    path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path("", views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
    path(
        "login/",
        auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="webportal/login.html"),
        name="login",
    ),
]
```

3.models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth


class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    """ this is account User model"""

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

4.forms.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth


class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    """ this is account User model"""

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

5.templates->webportal(myapp's name)->1.login.html ,

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load bootstrap3 %} {% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <h1>Login In</h1>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

2.signup.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load bootstrap3 %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'webportal:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}{% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-default" />
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
<!--  -->
```

6.project's urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from . import views


from . import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("hello/", views.HelloPage.as_view(), name="hello"),
    path("thanks/", views.Thankspage.as_view(), name="thanks"),
    path("core/", include("core.urls", namespace="core")),
    path("webportal/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("webportal/", include("webportal.urls", namespace="webportal")),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Actually, i have my custom login template so, In app's urls.py , I have passed argument template_name accordingly in as_view method. I dont why django engine searching for registration/login.html..

My errors:

```
Internal Server Error: /webportal/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pandi\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\pandi\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\pandi\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\pandi\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\pandi\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Users\pandi\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Users\pandi\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html
[18/Mar/2020 19:06:01] "GET /webportal/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 86610
```

7.settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for drf_api project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images")
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "y&^-h50qul((6$puv28xqy_a_fb*m4vr)y0copvu6d^o*c+8x&"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # "debug_toolbar",
    "core",
    # "ingredient",
    "webportal",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "rest_auth",
    "bootstrap3",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    # "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "drf_api.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [MEDIA_ROOT, TEMPLATE_DIR],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "drf_api.wsgi.application"


# Database
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "test_database",
        "USER": "root",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "",
        "PORT": "",
        "OPTIONS": {"init_command": "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"},
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/images/"
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "  DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication"
    ]
}

# this internal ips helps us by not letting others see that if we went into production
# in this way we can only get toolbar in our local machine only


# INTERTNAL_IPS = ["127.0.0.1"]
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "hello"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "thanks"
```

8. directory tree:

```
.vscode
src 
    |-core    (app one)
    |-drf_api  (project folder)
                  |-_pycache_
                  |- __init__.py
                  |- settings.py
                  |- urls.py
                  |- views.py
                  |-wsgi.py
    |-images
           |-uploads
    |-static
           |-core
           |-webportal
    |-templates
           |-base.html
           |-hello.html
           |-index.html
           |-thanks.html
    |-webportal  (app two)
            |-__pycache__
            |-migrations
            |-templates
                   |-webportal
                   |-login.html
                   |-signup.html
       |-__init__.py
       |-admin.py
       |-apps.py
       |-forms.py
       |-models.py
       |-tests.py
       |-urls.py
       |-views.py
   |- .gitignore
   |-manage.py
```

Comment: Can you share settings.py  with templete configuration?

Comment: please show template configuration at settings.py and show your static file directory structure name

Comment: can you share the project directory structure?

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT` is used to store uploads from the users. It shouldn't be included in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, it might be a security risk.

Comment: then whats the alternative way ? can u describe it to  me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same path for `django.contrib.auth.urls` and `webportal.urls`.

That means `webportal/login/` is matched by `django.contrib.auth.urls` first, which uses the template `registration/login.html`.

You can switch the order of the includes so that login is matched by the pattern in `webportal.urls` first.

```
path("webportal/", include("webportal.urls", namespace="webportal")),
path("webportal/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
```

Alternatively, since all you are changing is the template name, you could move the login template to `webportal/templates/registration/login.html`, remove your URL pattern, and let `django.contrib.auth.urls` handle logins.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alasdair

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be in settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "<project_name>/templates")
```

update this and try out

Comment: Not working. BASE_DIR contains the project directory root so . No need of mentioning like that.